# Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

why after use of redirect in codeigniter i have this error:

> Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many
>   redirects.

if use of this: `redirect('admin/hotel/insert', 'refresh');`, refresh page to be non-stop, burst.
what do i do?

my codes(`function`) in controller `hotel`:

```
function insert(){
    $this->load->view('admin/hotel_submit_insert');
        $today = jgmdate("j F Y");
        $data = array (
        'name' => $this->input->post('name', TRUE),
        'star' => $this->input->post('star', TRUE),
        'address' => $this->input->post('address', TRUE),
        'number_phone' => $this->input->post('number_phone', TRUE),
        'fax' => $this->input->post('fax', TRUE),
        'site' => $this->input->post('site', TRUE),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email', TRUE),
        'useradmin' => $this->input->post('useradmin', TRUE),
        'date' => $today ,
        );
        $this->db->insert('hotel_submits', $data);
        redirect('admin/hotel/insert'); // after use of this
    }
```

With respect

Comment: You probably need to have a stopping condition for redirect. Aren't you redirecting the user to the same page after the insert? You can also check if your database isn't full now of empty records because of this.

Comment: yes,it go to same page after the insert. Explain more. Do I need to change the code?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Okay, so you need to make sure that the insert happens only once.

So, You need to check if the post data is available before you run a redirect. What is happening here is that the code keeps inserting data and redirecting the page.

```
function insert(){

// If you are posting data do the insert
if (isset($this->input->post('name')) && strlen($this->input->post('name')) //just double checking.
{
    $today = jgmdate("j F Y");
    $data = array (
        'name' => $this->input->post('name', TRUE),
        'star' => $this->input->post('star', TRUE),
        'address' => $this->input->post('address', TRUE),
        'number_phone' => $this->input->post('number_phone', TRUE),
        'fax' => $this->input->post('fax', TRUE),
        'site' => $this->input->post('site', TRUE),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email', TRUE),
        'useradmin' => $this->input->post('useradmin', TRUE),
        'date' => $today ,
    );
    if($this->db->insert('hotel_submits', $data))
        redirect('admin/hotel/insert');
}

//And load the view
$this->load->view('admin/hotel_submit_insert');
```

}

Comment: that's hysterical, a copy/paste job 25 minutes later gets the answer.. nice.

Comment: Actually, there is a big red box in the php docs for `isset()` that points out that isset() should only be used for variables, `$this->input->post()` is a function.  and even if it DID work, it would ALWAYS be true.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this...

```
function insert(){

    // If you are posting data, do the insert
    if ($_POST)
    {
        $today = jgmdate("j F Y");
        $data = array (
            'name' => $this->input->post('name', TRUE),
            'star' => $this->input->post('star', TRUE),
            'address' => $this->input->post('address', TRUE),
            'number_phone' => $this->input->post('number_phone', TRUE),
            'fax' => $this->input->post('fax', TRUE),
            'site' => $this->input->post('site', TRUE),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email', TRUE),
            'useradmin' => $this->input->post('useradmin', TRUE),
            'date' => $today ,
        );
        $this->db->insert('hotel_submits', $data);
    }

    // then load the view no matter what
    $this->load->view('admin/hotel_submit_insert');
}
```